# Primefaces: How to solve DraggableRows throws IndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have implemented Draggable rows using primefaces onRowReorder event. When I drag the rows I get an IndexOutOfBoundException. I do not know why does this occurs and would like some help.

Controller.java

```
    public void onRowReorder(ReorderEvent event) {  

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        int tindex = event.getToIndex();

        List<DocumentPrintCollection> printCollectionsSorted = getPrintCollectionsSorted();
        DocumentPrintCollection printCollection = printCollectionsSorted.get(tindex);
        int newSort = printCollection.getSort();

        printCollection.setSort(newSort);
        
    }
```

viewDocument.xhtml

```
<div id="#{cc.clientId}">
    <p:dataTable id="printcollection" 
                 value="#{cc.attrs.printCollection}"
                 var="collection" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" first="0"
                 reflow="true"
                 sortBy="#{printCollection.sort}"
                 sortOrder="ascending"
                 draggableRows="true"
                 widgetVar="printcollection">
        <p:ajax event="rowReorder" listener="#{cc.attrs.model.onRowReorder}" process="@this"/>
```

I do not get this exception when I click the save button that is implemented in another .xhtml file.

MainPage.xhtml

```
<p:tab id="doclist" title="Reorder Document list">
                <div jsf:id="printlist" class="doc_materials">
                    <div class="ui-g">
                        <div class="ui-g-12">
                            <vwprn:viewDocument model="#{maskDocMaterialsController}"
                                                       printCollection="#{maskDocMaterialsController.printCollections}"
                                                       documents="#{maskDocMaterialsController.realDocuments}"
                                                       readOnly="#{maskDocMaterialsController.readOnly}"
                                                       documentNullText="no Dokument"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{not maskDocMaterialsController.readOnly}">
                        <div class="footer-column">             
                            <p:commandButton id="btnSavePrintCollectionDocumentsList" value="Save" icon="fa fa-check" 
                                             action="#{maskDocMaterialsController.save}"
                                             process="@this" update="printlist"/>
                        </div>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </div>
            </p:tab>
```

Stacktrace

```
Message: toIndex = 2
StackTrace: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: toIndex = 2
at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.subListRangeCheck(AbstractList.java:507)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.subList(ArrayList.java:1108)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.DraggableRowsFeature.decode(DraggableRowsFeature.java:74)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:72)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:509)
at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:117)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:606)
at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:159)
at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:691)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)
at javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer.visitTree(UINamingContainer.java:150)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)
at org.primefaces.component.api.UITabPanel.visitTree(UITabPanel.java:939)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:355)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:400)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:261)
at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:65)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:1008)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:55)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:177)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:707)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1637)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:757)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:372)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:239)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

The class maskDocMaterialsController.java updates the reordered list in the database. I think the exception occurs as the database index is unknown before saving, not sure if I am right.

If you need any more information, please do let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try with the latest version of PrimeFaces?

Comment: @JasperdeVries I am using primfaces 10. Is this a common issue in older versions or ?

Comment: I don't know. It's just common practice to first try with the latest version. If you have the issue with the latest version, please create a minimal runnable reproducer so we can have a look. https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Comment: Also, what is the stracktrace? Is the issue caused by PrimeFaces at all?

Comment: @JasperdeVries I have added the stacktrace in the main question.

Comment: Alright. Please don't use irrelevant tags. This question cannot be answered by a Java SE expert for example.